# How can I possibly accomplish this Javascript highlighting technique?

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="false" style="margin:-0.2em 1em; font-family:New Century Schoolbook; font-size:20; color:black; line-height:170%">
        <span style="margin-left:1.7em">Jenny was cute!</span>
        <span style="margin-left:1.7em">She looked happy with the instructor.</span>
        <span style="margin-left:1.7em">Can we meet her again?</span><br>
        <span style="margin-left:18em">Sakura</span>
    </div>
```

Here is some HTML I have created to match a client's needs.  The margin-left between each one is so that I can insert a separate image in between each sentence (user selection turns completely weird when images are in the HTML).  The user needs to be able to select, highlight, and add memos to sections like in the iBook app.  However, unlike the iBook app, it needs to happen with **formatted text**.  So it needs to be selectable, editable, AND support bold, italic, and underline in the same view.  Here is the Javascript I have come up with (the HTML and the result from the Javascript are not standards compliant, but I don't care since this is not going to be a webpage and I'm fed up):

```
function addHighlight(className, id)
{
    var html = '';
    var sel = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var container = document.createElement('JimSpan');
    container.id = id;
    container.className = className;
    container.appendChild(sel.extractContents());

    var arrElements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for(i = 0; i < arrElements.length-1; i++)
    {
        if(!arrElements[i].innerText.match(/\S/))
        {
            arrElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(arrElements[i]);
        }
    }

    sel.insertNode(container); 

    return 'js: ADDED HIGHLIGHT';
}
```

The reason I have to use "JimSpan" and not "Span" is because the user ALSO needs to be able to delete the notes while the page is not displaying, which means I have to edit it manually with regular expressions.  Since there are tons of spans I will have no idea when mine actually ends.  This works well with one exception.  If the user selects all of one element and part of another, the result is this:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="false" style="margin:-0.2em 1em; font-family:New Century Schoolbook; font-size:20; color:black; line-height:170%">
    <jimspan id="memo0" class="pinkHilite"><span style="margin-left:1.7em">Jenny was cute!</span>
    <span style="margin-left:1.7em">She</span></jimspan><span style="margin-left:1.7em"> looked happy with the instructor.</span>
    <span style="margin-left:1.7em">Can we meet her again?</span><br>
    <span style="margin-left:18em">Sakura</span>
</div>
```

As you can see in the middle, the split resulted in the sentence **She looked happy with the instructor** being split into two spans, each with the margin-left, and I am left with a huge gap in the middle of the sentence.  I will accept either of the following:

1) A way for me to produce the following (technically invalid, but displays fine) HTML (I don't mind editing the current range with regex if there is a way to do that):

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="false" style="margin:-0.2em 1em; font-family:New Century Schoolbook; font-size:20; color:black; line-height:170%">
    <jimspan id="memo0" id="pinkHilite"><span style="margin-left:1.7em">Jenny was cute!</span>
    <span style="margin-left:1.7em">She</jimspan> looked happy with the instructor.</span>
    <span style="margin-left:1.7em">Can we meet her again?</span><br>
    <span style="margin-left:18em">Sakura</span>
</div>
```

2) A way to force the user selection to only encompass the inside of 1 span (the selection must change, not just the affected highlight region).

Please help save my sanity -*_*_-;

Comment: Tried `document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "pink")`? Or do you need more control over the highlight styling than just a background colour?

Comment: Yes, that won't cut it.  It is not consistent.  Sometimes it adds a span and sometimes it simply adds a class to the current DOM styling element (<i> becomes <i class="Apple-style-span"...>, etc).  Also, I am using an image, not a color.  Last but not least, I need to be able to have one area that corresponds to the area of the memo that the user wrote, and execCommand splits the area into multiple spans sometimes.

Comment: I need to be able to remove the highlight so that it returns to the state it was in before the highlight was applied, and that won't happen with this level of inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is the easiest solution, and quite achievable using `Range` and `Selection` objects (ruling out IE < 9, which doesn't matter for a `UIWebView` but could to someone wanting to do similar in a browser). The following will limit the selection to the element containing the point at which the user started selecting (note: for the sake of illustration, it only works with mouse-based selection):

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U4smu/

Code:

```
function isOrIsDescendantOf(node, ancestor) {
    while (node) {
        if (node === ancestor) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}

function selectionIsBackwards(sel) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
    range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
    var backwards = range.collapsed;
    range.detach();
    return backwards;
}    

document.onmouseup = function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var containerEl = sel.anchorNode;
    if (containerEl ) {
        if (containerEl .nodeType == 3) {
            containerEl = containerEl.parentNode;
        }

        if (!isOrIsDescendantOf(sel.focusNode, containerEl)) {
            var backwards = selectionIsBackwards(sel);
            var range = document.createRange();
            if (backwards) {
                range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
                range.setEnd(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            } else {
                range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
                range.setEnd(containerEl, containerEl.childNodes.length);
            }
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!  You really are a Javascript specialist as your profile indicates ;).  I am a Javascript primate >_<

Comment: @borrrden: This is also my specialist field within JavaScript :)